# Default setting programs r not coming

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have accidentally changed the default programs and now everything starts with notepad and when I try to SET PROGRAMS ACESS AND COMPUTER DEFAULTS a notepad open please help me I very worried about Pls answer as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Please check this tutorial: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2630-default-programs-set-programs-default-associations.html . You need to go to "Control Panel" and click "Default programs", from there you can set manually the desired programs.